# Jquery parse xhr.responseText

Tags: json, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

```
var data  = xhr.responseText;
```

When I output this `console.log(xhr.responseText)`. Below is my output

```
["{id:1,name\":\"JOHN\",\"city\":\"null\"}"
,"{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\,\"city\":\"null\"}"]
```

How do I get `id`, `name`. I tried like this `data.id` but I get this error

> jquery JSON.parse: unexpected end of data.

**Update**

I am using code igniter with data mapper so my data mapper is giving that json response. Do you know, how I can resolve it.

Comment: Thats not valid JSON when unescaped. The server side code that sends this is where the fix is needed.

Comment: It looks like you might be double json encoding it.

Comment: @Kevin B:How do I parse my above response using jquery.Can you post a small snippet.My response is in data now.

Comment: Can you post what your response is?

Comment: @Kevin B:I have already posted it.["{id:1,name\":\"JOHN\",\"city\":\"null\"}"
,"{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"MICHEAL\,\"city\":\"null\"}"]

Comment: It's invalid. fix it first.

Comment: @KevinB:I am using code igniter with data mapper so my data mapper is giving that json response.Do you know, How I can resolve it.

Comment: @techfoobar:I am using code igniter with data mapper so my data mapper is giving that json response.Do you know, How I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You've already been told what the problem is in the comments: the JSON generated by the server is invalid. You are probably not using a library to encode your JSON, don't ever encode it by hand.

Your JSON should probably look like the following (when pretty printed) http://jsfiddle.net/7FKWr/

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "JOHN", "city": null},
  {"id": 2, "name": "MICHEAL", "city": null}
]
```

Comment: :I am using code igniter with data mapper so my data mapper is giving that json response.Do you know, How I can resolve it.

Comment: @user2261231 I don't mean to be rude, but how do you expect someone to help you if you don't show your code? Don't spam all the commenters

Comment: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954174/code-igniter-with-data-mapper-giving-in-valid-json